# Cannot pass javascript variable to php page under jquery .click() method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my code below `window.location.href` is not working. When I use it outside the `.click` function it works but inside it does not.

```
<script> 
   $('#para').click(function(e) {      
         var getID= $("#"+e.target.id).text(); 
         ID = getID.substring(getID.indexOf("id: ")+3,getID.length);
         alert ("success");
         window.location.href = "specificImagePage.php?ID=" + ID;
   }
</script>
```

The below code is (*JUST SHOWING WHERE PARA ID IS*) used to retrieve images from database and when the user clicks on an image I want to pass that image id to next page, so that it can again be used.

```
<div id = "para">   
<?php
   $j;
   $files = glob("upload/*.*");
   require 'config.php'; //database config file
   for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)

   {

   $image = $files[$i];

   $info = pathinfo($image);
   $file_name =  basename($image);

   $sql = "SELECT id,address, cuisine, imageName FROM postfood WHERE imageName = '".$file_name."' ";

   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   echo "filename is".$file_name;
   echo (mysqli_num_rows($result));
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $row;
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         echo '<div  id = '.$j.' style="float:left;margin:2.5em;"><a href = "" ><img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" id = '.$j.' width="250em" height="250em"/>'. "<br>address: " . $row["address"]. "<br> -cuisine: " . $row["cuisine"]. "<br> -imageName: " . $row["imageName"]."<br> -id: " . $row["id"]. '</a></div>';
         ++$j;
 ?>
</div>
```

The code for my specificImagePage.php is:

```
<?php
                if(isset($_GET["ID"]))
                {
                    $uid = $_GET["ID"];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo ("no ");
                }
    ?>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET["ID"]))
    {
       $uid = $_GET["ID"];
    }
    else
    {
       echo ("no ");
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the actual problem you are having as well the results of your debugging session on said problem.

Comment: check if you use $_GET['ID'] to get the image Id

Comment: what is the problem? redirect did not work? Is #para a link?

Comment: please have a look again, I have edited my post (sorry for messing up things - new member)

Comment: hm...you call `window.location.href = "specificImagePage.php?ID=" + ID;` but on your page you check $_GET["w1"] I'm confused... shouldn't it be $_GET['ID']?

Comment: I edited it already to ID, still not working

Comment: ok, can you describe what you get when you click the div? Redirect works with the correct id but the php page echo 'no'? Or ID is incorrect? Or even redirect is not working?

Comment: but you can see redirect ID is correct in browser address or it is empty?

Comment: Have you checked that `getID`, `ID` have proper values?

Comment: Sorry for the earlier reply, I was getting redirected because I was using the page address in my anchor tag on which .click function is applied,, if I don't pass in address in my anchor tag I am not getting redirected,if I do I get no (without any name pair in web address)

Comment: @u_mulder I have tried it with simple variable like ID = Hello ,,still does not work

Comment: And the function itself called?

Comment: @u_mulder that works,,that's what the big problem is, it works well outside .click function with simple variable values but just not inside it

Comment: It could be a scope issue. Is your function defined in a .js file that is linked to the document? If so, the .js file is not within scope to see the window.location.href variable

Comment: @Matt no my js is not in a separate file, but I think it could be a scope issue, you know any work-arounds like declaring window.location.href outside function and giving it real value inside??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the anchor tag in my echo statement

```
echo '<div  id = '.$j.' style="float:left;margin:2.5em;"><a href = "" ><img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" id = '.$j.' width="250em" height="250em"/>'. "<br>address: " . $row["address"]. "<br> -cuisine: " . $row["cuisin.....
```

Deleted the anchor tag in above code and now I am able to pass my variable